# How to get records from table having join with mapping table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to get records from table having join with mapping table

Below example:

**User** table

```
ID | Name
---+-------
1  | ABC
2  | xyz
3  | NYS
```

**Feature** table

```
ID | Name
---+------
1  | F1
2  | F2
3  | F3
4  | F4
```

**Mapping** table

```
ID  |  UserID | FeatureID
----+---------+----------
1   |    1    |    1
2   |    1    |    2
3   |    2    |    2
4   |    3    |    1
```

I need the result to look like this:

```
UserName | FeatureName |  IsMap 
---------+-------------+------------
ABC      |    F1       |   True
ABC      |    F2       |   True
ABC      |    F3       |   False
ABC      |    F4       |   False
XYZ      |    F1       |   False
XYZ      |    F2       |   True 
XYZ      |    F3       |   False
XYZ      |    F4       |   False
NYS      |    F1       |   True 
NYS      |    F2       |   False
NYS      |    F3       |   False
NYS      |    F4       |   False
```

Please help me with this..

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is very simple SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Start by `cross join`ing your `User` data to your `Feature` data to get all combinations.  You can then `left join` this to your `Mapping` table to check if a mapping exists.  Where this returns a `null` value, you don't have a match, which you can handle with a `case` expression:

```
declare @User table(ID int,Name nvarchar(100));
insert into @User values (1,'ABC'),(2,'xyz'),(3,'NYS');

declare @Feature table(ID int,Name nvarchar(100));
insert into @Feature values (1,'F1'),(2,'F2'),(3,'F3'),(4,'F4');

declare @Mapping table(ID int,UserID int,FeatureID int);
insert into @Mapping values (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,2,2),(4,3,1);

select u.Name as UserName
        ,f.Name as FeatureName
        ,case when m.ID is not null then 'True' else 'False' end as IsMap
from @User u
    cross join @Feature f
    left join @Mapping m
        on(u.ID = m.UserID
            and f.ID = m.FeatureID
            )
order by u.Name
        ,f.Name;
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------------+-------+
| UserName | FeatureName | IsMap |
+----------+-------------+-------+
| ABC      | F1          | True  |
| ABC      | F2          | True  |
| ABC      | F3          | False |
| ABC      | F4          | False |
| NYS      | F1          | True  |
| NYS      | F2          | False |
| NYS      | F3          | False |
| NYS      | F4          | False |
| xyz      | F1          | False |
| xyz      | F2          | True  |
| xyz      | F3          | False |
| xyz      | F4          | False |
+----------+-------------+-------+
```